# How to find the next expiration date in Php

Tags: php

In my Php project, i want to find out the expiration date ( eg,today is my joining date then my expiry date is the next month  ie validity is 1 month)

What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Find out when, in what context? Needs more detail.

Comment: duplicate of any ["How to get the next x date"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+next+month). Please use the search function. There are hundreds of similar questions by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");// current date

$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +2 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +30 days")
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to look at http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, look at the examples.

Comment: As much as this is correct, RTFM style answers and/or comments are discouraged.